# Organizing and printing information by a specific row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a code that takes in some data, and I end up with a csv file that looks like the following:

```
1,Steak,Martins
2,Fish,Martins
2,Steak,Johnsons
4,Veggie,Smiths
3,Chicken,Johnsons
1,Veggie,Johnsons
```

where the first column is a quantity, the second column is the type of item (in this case the meal), and the third column is an identifier (in this case it is family name). I need to print this information to a text file in a specific way:

```
Martins
1 Steak
2 Fish
Johnsons
2 Steak
3 Chicken
1 Veggie
Smiths
4 Veggie
```

So What I want is the family name followed by what that family ordered. I wrote the following code to accomplish this, but it doesn't seem to be quite there.

```
import csv
orders = "orders.txt"
messy_orders = "needs_sorting.csv"

    with open(messy_orders, 'rb') as orders_for_sorting, open(orders, 'a') as final_orders_file:
        comp = []
        reader_sorting = csv.reader(orders_for_sorting)
        for row in reader_sorting:
            test_bit = [row[2]]
            if test_bit not in comp:
                comp.append(test_bit)
                final_orders_file.write(row[2])
                for row in reader_sorting:
                    if [row[2]] == test_bit:
                        final_orders_file.write(row[0], row[1])

            else:
                print "already here"
                continue
```

What I end up with is the following

```
Martins
2 Fish
```

Additionally, I never see it print "already here" though I think I should if it were working properly. What I suspect is happening is that the program goes through the second for loop, then exits the program without continuing the first loop. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to make it go back to the original loop once it has identified and printed all instances of a given family name in a file. I thought The reason I have it set up this way, is so that I can get the family name written as a header. Otherwise I would just sort the file by family name. Please note that after running the orders through my first program, I did manage to sort everything such that each row represents the complete quantity of that type of food for that family (there are no recurring instances of a row containing both Steak and Martins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that you solve with a dictionary; which will accumulate your items by the last name (family name) of your file.

The second thing you have to do is accumulate a total of each type of meal - keeping in mind that the data you are reading is a string, and not an integer that you can add, so you'll have to do some conversion.

To put all that together, try this snippet:

```
import csv

d = dict()

with open(r'd:/file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # if the family name doesn't
        # exist in our dictionary,
        # set it with a default value of a blank dictionary
        if row[2] not in d:
            d[row[2]] = dict()

        # If the meal type doesn't exist for this
        # family, set it up as a key in their dictionary
        # and set the value to int value of the count
        if row[1] not in d[row[2]]:
            d[row[2]][row[1]] = int(row[0])
        else:
            # Both the family and the meal already
            # exist in the dictionary, so just add the
            # count to the total
            d[row[2]][row[1]] += int(row[0])
```

Once you run through that loop, `d` looks like this:

```
{'Johnsons': {'Chicken': 3, 'Steak': 2, 'Veggie': 1},
 'Martins': {'Fish': 2, 'Steak': 1},
 'Smiths': {'Veggie': 4}}
```

Now its just a matter of printing it out:

```
for family,data in d.iteritems():
   print('{}'.format(family))
   for meal, total in data.iteritems():
       print('{} {}'.format(total, meal))
```

At the end of the loop, you'll have:

```
Johnsons
3 Chicken
2 Steak
1 Veggie
Smiths
4 Veggie
Martins
2 Fish
1 Steak
```

You can later improve this snippet by using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Ah. Great. I thought about using a dictionary before, but wasn't sure how to seperate out name from the meal and keep everything ordered properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First time replier so here's a go. Have you considered keeping track of the orders and then writing to a file? I tried something using a dict based approach and it seems to work fine. The idea was to index by the family name and store a list of pairs containing the order quantities and types.

You may also want to consider the readability of your code - it's hard to follow and debug. However, what I think is happening is the line

```
for line in reader_sorting:
```

Iterates through reader_sorting. You read the 1st name, extract the family name, and later proceed to iterate again in reader_sorting. This time you start at the 2nd line, which family name matches, and you print it successfully. The rest of the line don't match, but you still iterate through them all. Now you've finished iterating through reader_sorting, and the loop finishes, even though in the outer loop you've read only one line.

One solution may be to create another iterator in the outer for loop and not expend the iterator that loop goes through. However, then you still need to deal with the possibility of double counting, or keeping track of indices. Another way may be to keep of the orders by family as you iterate.

```
import csv

orders = {}

with open('needs_sorting.csv') as file:
    needs_sorting = csv.reader(file)
    for amount, meal, family in needs_sorting:
        if family not in orders:
            orders[family] = []            
        orders[family].append((amount, meal))

with open('orders.txt', 'a') as file:
    for family in orders:
        file.write('%s\n' % family)
        for amount, meal in orders[family]:
            file.write('%s %s\n' % (amount, meal))
```

Comment: This will not sum the totals.

Comment: Nothing was said about summing the totals.

Comment: Look at the question and the output required.